# Bin Packing And Preemptive Multi-Core Scheduling

Tags: partition-problem, scheduling, packing

I am trying to solve a preemptive multi-core scheduling problem, where the input is the tasks. The number of cores `M` can be decided after seeing the input tasks. I need to output the minimal `M` such that the run time is as long as the maximal task length.

I feel this is related to bin packing with fragmentation, but fragmentation does not require linear constraints.

I doubt I am the first to study this problem but have been unable to find a name for this problem. Does it have a name?

Comment: The name of this kind of problems is "work-stealing scheduling". You can find thousands of papers on Google using this keyword

Comment: That has dynamically spawns threads for a fixed number of cores. In my problem, the cores is the unknown.